# Here I have shop and user latitude and longitude and i want to show shop list in order by

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js, latitude-longitude, google-latitude

Here I have shop and user latitude and longitude i want to show my shop list between user and shop  latitude and longitude . how i can do it in sequlize orm

```js
 const latitude = req.query.latitude; // user latitude 
 const longitude = req.query.longitude; // user longitutde 

 const shopLists = await Shop.findAll({
            limit,offset,
            attributes:["latitude","longitude"],
            where:{
                category_id:category_id,
                status:1,
            },
            include :{
                model:Category,attributes:['id','name']
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const limit;
// what is offset?
const shopLists = await Shop.findAll({
    where: {
        longitude: {
            [Op.ne]: null,
        },
        latitude: {
            [Op.ne]: null,
        },
        [Op.and]: [
            Sequelize.where(
                Sequelize.fn(
                    'ST_Distance',
                    Sequelize.fn('point', Sequelize.col('longitude'), Sequelize.col('latitude')),
                    Sequelize.fn('point', longitude, latitude),
                ),
                '<',
                limit,
            ),
        ],
    },
})
```

Comment: bro offset is page number ..btw this does not work I did pass user latitude and longitude but I can,t get data its returns an empty array. terminal show this  ST_Distance(point(23.7873, 90.3514), point(23.7873, 90.3514)) IS NULL ..